# How can I do this python list comprehension in NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masking, bitmask

Let's say I have an array of values, `r`, which range anywhere from `0` to `1`. I want to remove all values that are some threshold value away from the median. Let's assume here that that threshold value is `0.5`, and `len(r) = 3000`. Then to mask out all values outside of this range, I can do a simple list comprehension, which I like:

`mask = np.array([ri < np.median(r)-0.5 or ri > np.median(r)+0.5 for ri in r])`

And if I use a timer on it:

```
import time
import numpy as np

start = time.time()
r = np.random.random(3000)
m = np.median(r)
maxr,minr = m-0.5, m+0.5
mask = [ri<minr or ri>maxr for ri in r]
end = time.time()
print('Took %.4f seconds'%(end-start))
```

`>>> Took 0.0010 seconds`

Is there a faster way to do this list comprehension and make the mask using `NumPy`?

---

**Edit:**

I've tried several suggestions below, including:

- An element-wise or operator: `(r<minv) | (r>maxv)`
- A Numpy logical or: `r[np.logical_or(r<minr, r>maxr)]`
- A absolute difference boolean array: `abs(m-r) > 0.5`

And here is the average time each one took after 300 runs through:

```
Python list comprehension: 0.6511 ms
Elementwise or: 0.0138 ms
Numpy logical or: 0.0241 ms
Absolute difference: 0.0248 ms
```

As you can see, the elementwise Or was always the fastest, by nearly a factor of two (don't know how that would scale with array elements). Who knew.

Comment: `[ri<-maxr ` is the minus sign a typo here?

Comment: @ayhan yea sorry, also the min and max were flopped

Comment: Try `(r  > maxr) | (r < minr)` instead. `|` is for element-wise OR.

Comment: Are you sure that `maxr` must be less then `minr` or, maybe, you want to use `and` instead of `or`?

Comment: @Arnial No, one value can never both less than the minimum and greater than the maximum

Comment: @jphollowed You should change `maxr,minr = m-0.5, m+0.5` to 
`minr,maxr = m-0.5, m+0.5`, otherwise you will have all elements in mask.

Comment: @Arnial It's a bit weird, but I like to mask like this: `r[~mask]`

Comment: @ayhan Your suggestion was fastest, see my edit. Make an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: I think that's just random deviation. You can accept either one, I think they are both nice. :)

Comment: @ayhan What do you mean random deviation? It was very consistently faster.

Comment: I believe `|` and `np.logical_or` are using the same methods so the difference should stem from something else http://i.imgur.com/7Y4frKM.png `abs` could take longer though, you are right.

Comment: @ayhan no they are not same. [`|` is bitwise_or](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_or.html). They will work same way only on boolean arrays. I have same results on performance tests as you. But i believe that it's hardware dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use numpy conditional selections to create new array, without those values.

```
start = time.time()
m = np.median(r)
maxr,minr = m-0.5, m+0.5
filtered_array = r[ (r < minr) | (r > maxr) ]
end = time.time()
print('Took %.4f seconds'%(end-start))
```

`filtered_array` is slice of `r` without masked values (all values that will be later removed by mask already removed in `filtered_array`).

Update: used shorter syntax suggested by @ayhan.

Comment: This is fastest, thanks. Though your original answer using `np.logical_or()` was slower.

Answer (score 4):

One liner...

```
new_mask = abs(np.median(r) - r) > 0.5
```

Comment: Very useful when the tails of distributions are needed.  I like clarity.